# Text-overflow: ellipsis on non-text value

Tags: html, css, ellipsis

I have a something like this:

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="element">
      My super text <span>something</span>
      <div>Hello world</div>
      anything.
    <div>This is long</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

With the following style:

```css
.container {
  display: block;
  background-color: red;
  width: 50px;
}

.element {
  font-family: monospace;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Is there a way to display HTML elements inline but with an ellipse if the size of the child is bigger than the size of its container?

If I put only text instead of HTML it works fine but with HTML it doesn't.
I tried to put a `display: flex` on the `element` class but the dots are not shown and some html element like `button` are cut in the middle.

Code can be tested on https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-ow7cqb

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add element style to child element (div or etc)

like this :

```
.element, .element div {
  font-family: monospace;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-kahxsq?file=style.css

Comment: Thanks but I wanted it to be on one line. I did a solution inspired by yours:
```.container {
  display: block;
  background-color: red;
  width: 50px;
}

.element {
  font-family: monospace;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.element div {
  display: inline;
}
```

Comment: aha, good job :)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to add inline style to the child element.

```
.container {
  display: block;
  background-color: red;
  width: 50px;
}

.element {
  font-family: monospace;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.element div {
  display: inline;
}
```